# Finding integer power roots

Tags: algorithm, exponentiation

What is the best (most efficient) algorithm for finding all integer power roots of a number?

That is, **given a number** `n`, I want to **find** `b` (base) and `e` (exponent) such that

> **n = b<sup>e</sup>**

I want to obtain all the possible value pairs of `b` and `e`

Ps: `n` `b` and `e` are to be **positive integers** .

Comment: Does `e` have to be an integer ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that , I have updated the question

Comment: I am still searching to find something . been doing that for more than 45 mins

Comment: If your problem is prime factorization, first find all primes less than `n/2` and create an array of int of size n/2 + 1 name it A set to zero in start up, then for each of the prime numbers (p) test `n/p == 0` or not, until n/p == 0, set n /= p and increment A[p], then you will have prime factorization, If you want faster method for this ask it in new question.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri there is no need to go to `n/2`, just go to `sqrt(n)`.  Any factor that is left over is automatically the last prime.

Comment: @btilly yes you are right, but in all this can be done faster, this is just nave algorithm.

Comment: @Gautam K: The problem you defined is actually _finding all integer power roots_ - not exponentiation. Exponentiation is finding `Y=X**a` for the known `X` and `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think brute force approach should work: try all `e`s from 2 (1 is a trivial solution) and up, taking `r = n ^ 1/e`, a `double`. If `r` is less than 2, stop. Otherwise, compute `ceil(r)^e` and `floor(r)^e`, and compare them to `n` (you need `ceil` and `floor` to compensate for errors in floating point representations). Assuming your integers fit in 64 bits, you would not need to try more than 64 values of `e`.

Here is an example in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
typedef long long i64;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    if (argc == 0) return 0;
    stringstream ss(argv[1]);
    i64 n;
    ss >> n;
    cout << n << ", " << 1 << endl;
    for (int e = 2 ; ; e++) {
        double r = pow(n, 1.0 / e);
        if (r < 1.9) break;
        i64 c = ceil(r);
        i64 f = floor(r);
        i64 p1 = 1, p2 = 1;
        for (int i = 0 ; i != e ; i++, p1 *= c, p2 *= f);
        if (p1 == n) {
            cout << c << ", " << e << endl;
        } else if (p2 == n) {
            cout << f << ", " << e << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When invoked with 65536, it produces this output:

```
65536, 1
256, 2
16, 4
4, 8
2, 16
```

Comment: Seems plausible , Can you please clarify the solution with some code ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: It is the correct idea for a perfect solution. You only have to try `e` from `2` to `log2(n)` (logarithm base 2). The only thing is that exponentiation code `for (int i = 0 ; i != e ; i++, p1 *= c, p2 *= f);` is far from optimal (you can do less than `2*log2(e)` multiplications instead of `e` multiplications). But the main concept is right anyway.

Comment: @SergeDundich I kept the naive `power(c,e)` code because `e` has a low hard bound of 64. Smart algorithm of `power(c,e)` would create more questions (even the `for` loop I have there now might benefit from a comment; a `log2` power algorithm would be even less obvious) so I kept the trivial algorithm.

Answer (score 7):

First find the prime factorization of `n`: `n = p1e1 p2e2 p3e3 ...`

Then find the greatest common divisor `g` of `e1`, `e2`, `e3`, ... by using the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Now for any factor `e` of `g`, you can use:

`b = p1e1/e p2e2/e p3e3/e ...`

And you have `n = be`.

Comment: Actually I was trying to implement a prime factorization algorithm and I needed to solve this problem . Ironically you are asking me to find the prime factors.

Comment: @ChingPing: It is very far from great approach. **Finding integer power roots** is very simple polynomial-time problem while integer factorization is very complicated problem with no polynomial-time algorithm known.

Comment: @SergeDundich Is it polynomial if n is very very large? otherwise i dont see your point as finding primes for small numbers is also polynomial! and even better we have algos like rho pollard for big numbers! ALSO please note problem is "Finding ALL integer power roots"

Comment: @ChingPing: "Is it polynomial if n is very very large?" Of course it is. Talking about polynomial (of input size that is `P(s) = P(log2(n))`) running time is talking about running time `t(s)=O(P(s))` for **any possible** `n` and thus for any possible `s=log2(n)` including very very large.

Comment: @ChingPing: And there is no polynomial-time algorithm for [integer factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) problem known. All known algorithms including Pollard rho, Quadratic Sieve, General Number Field Sieve (best known universal algorithm) are much slower than polynomial.

Comment: @ChingPing: And of course I'm talking about "Finding **ALL** integer power roots".

Comment: @SergeDundich can you tell us the solution?

Comment: @ChingPing: "can you tell us the solution?" Solution of what? "Finding ALL integer power roots"? I can but dasblinkenlight already did this for integrated integer number types (small numbers up to 52-bit). If you have very long `n` with arbitrary length (say 1Gb or more) then the idea is the same: you try every `e` from 2 to `log2(n)` then find `e`-power root (largest `x` that `x**e <= n`) and if it is the exact power root (i.e. `x**e == n`) then you found a non-trivial solution `b = x, e` then you repeat the operation with `n = x` or otherwise go to `e = e+1`.

Answer (score 3):

Mix the approaches of interjay and dasblinkenlight. First find all small prime factors (if any) and their exponents in the prime factorisation of `n`. The appropriate value of 'small' depends on `n`, for medium sized `n`, `p <= 100` can be sufficient, for *large* `n`, `p <= 10000` or `p <= 10^6` may be more appropriate. If you find any small prime factors, you know that `e` must divide the greatest common divisor of all exponents you found. Quite often, that `gcd` will be 1. Anyway, the range of possible exponents will be reduced, if `n` has no small prime factors, you know that `e <= log(n)/log(small_limit)`, which is a good reduction from `log(n)/log(2)`, if you have found a couple of small prime factors, the `gcd` of their exponents is `g`, and the remaining cofactor of `n` is `m`, you only need to check the divisors of `g` not exceeding `log(m)/log(small_limit)`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the dimensions of the task whether my approach will suite your needs.

First of all there is one obvious solution: e = 1, right?
From then on if you want to find all the solutions: all the algorithms I can think of require to find some prime factor of n. If this is just a single independent task nothing better than brute force on the primes can be done (if I am not wrong). After you find the first prime factor p and its corresponding exponent (i.e the highest number k such that p^k / n) you need to check for e only the divisors of k. For every such exponent l (again l iterates all divisors of k) you can use binary search to see if the lth root of n is integer (equivalent to finding new solution).

Comment: "(if I am not wrong)" You are wrong. The [integer factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) has much faster algorithms than "brute force on the primes". And _finding all integer power roots_ that original question asks is much simpler (polynomial time) problem.

Comment: As some people might say: "The only thing better than being right is being wrong." Thank you for educating me.
PS: Only short time after I posted I realized the solution I propose is something in-between and I could hardly think of a setting of the  problem for which my solution will be optimal (probably factorizing huge number for which you know there is very small prime factor?).