# finding all the power roots in clojure

Tags: clojure

This is a rehash of [Finding integer power roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635067/finding-integer-power-roots) but in clojure:

How do i find ALL the integer roots of a number?

So I want a function:

```
(defn roots [ex num] .....)
```

that when called gives:

```
(roots 4 81) => [3, -3, 3i, -3i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user> (defn nth-root
          [n x]
        (long (Math/pow x (/ 1.0 n))))
#'user/nth-root
user> (nth-root 4 81)
3
```

To be honest, I do not know the standardized way to handle
a complex number in Clojure. You might have to implement
your own `Complex` record, using `defrecord`.

Comment: is there a canoical java one?

Comment: I could not find the equivalent function under `java.lang.Math` of Java 6. However, I think `Math/pow` provides a satisfactory solution.

Comment: so the problem is, there are actually four 4th roots. I need a function that can list all of them, not just the most likely one.

Comment: Clojure does not come with its build-in complex-number support. To answer more in detail, I hope you clarify how you handle complex numbers in your program; importing an existing Java library or implementing your own Clojure library.

Comment: yeah... I think the external library idea is the best see below answer

Answer (score 2):

The best library I found for Maths is the apache commons math library

to use add this to your project.clj

```
[org.apache.commons/commons-math3 "3.0"]
```

it comes with an nth-root method built in and the following can be wrappers:

```
(import org.apache.commons.math3.complex.Complex)

(defn complex
  ([re] (complex re 0))
  ([re im]
      (Complex/valueOf re im)))

(defn nth-root [#^Complex c m] (seq (.nthRoot c m)))

(defmethod print-method
  Complex
  [this w]
  (print (format "(%f %fi)" (re this) (im this))))

(nth-root (complex 1 4) 6)
;; => ((1.235513 0.277543i) (0.377397 1.208757i) (-0.858115 0.931214i) (-1.235513 -0.277543i) (-0.377397 -1.208757i) (0.858115 -0.931214i))
```